# I can't get the jQuery datepicker to show on my page after loading with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-datepicker

My main page is index.php. I'm loading a section of the page with AJAX and I would like to also load a datepicker in the same section I got all relevant JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/datepicker/jquery.datePicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/datepicker/date.js"></script>
```

I hope i'm not missing anything, the CSS is copied into my main css file.

and here's how the ajax looks like, at least the callback part:

```
xmlhttp12.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp12.readyState == 4) {
        if(document.getElementById("corpcrm").innerHTML=raspuns[0]){    
             $(function()
                    {           
                        $('#datepicker')            
                            .datePicker({inline:true})          

                    });
```

Now i know there aren't any problems with the the rest of the code as i've been using the very same thing for a while now, somehow I can't get the jQuery part right.

i tried adding a div directly to index.html and adding

```
<script type="text/javascript">
               $(document).ready(function(){
                 $("#test").datepicker();
               });
             </script>
```

in the head. Firebug finds an error related to it that says

```
$('#test').datepicker() is not a function
```

The problem is now solved. I wasn't loading jquery-ui properly, was missing a > at the end of a script, thanks for the help guys.

Comment: I don't think you have to wrap the jquery code in a 'ready' handler `$(function() { ...});`. Also, is the id #datepicker correct ? Are you sure the element is appended to the page before calling .datepicker() ?

Comment: the ID exists, i check for it with an alert right before the function, also i've tried not wrapping it into a function and I thought that was the problem. I'm starting to think I'm doing something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: And what about the `if` statement ? Have you tried debugging to see if your code gets reached ?

Comment: yes I've done the debugging. The code stops at either $(function or $('#datepicker') (when i don't wrap it in the function.

Comment: I can't help but think I'm doing something wrong with jQuery since it's the first time i've used it

Comment: Syntax is ok so I'm out of ideas...

Comment: is jQuery loaded correctly ? add this to the page (anywhere after the jQuery library is loaded) to confirm -> `if (jQuery) {  
alert('jQuery is loaded!');  
} `

Comment: yep, added it in the exact same spot i'm trying to load the datepicker in, says it's loaded.